# How do I avoid repeating long formulas in Excel when working with comparisons?

Tags: excel, error-handling, excel-formula, boolean

I know that something like the following

```
=IF(ISERROR(LONG_FORMULA), 0, LONG_FORMULA)
```

can be replaced with

```
=IFERROR(LONG_FORMULA, 0)
```

However I am looking for an expression to avoid having to type `REALLY_LONG_FORMULA` twice in

```
=IF(REALLY_LONG_FORMULA < threshold, 0, REALLY_LONG_FORMULA)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to come up with the following:

```
=IFERROR(EXP(LN(REALLY_LONG_FORMULA – threshold)) + threshold, 0)
```

It works by utilizing the fact that the log of a negative number produces an error and that `EXP` and `LN` are inverses of each other.

The biggest benefit of this is that it avoids accidentally introducing errors into your spreadsheet when you change something in one copy of `REALLY_LONG_FORMULA` without remembering to apply the same change to the other copy of `REALLY_LONG_FORMULA` in your `IF` statement.

Greater than comparisons as in

```
=IF(REALLY_LONG_FORMULA>=threshold,0,REALLY_LONG_FORMULA)
```

can be replaced with

```
=IFERROR(threshold-EXP(LN(threshold-REALLY_LONG_FORMULA)),0)
```

Example below (provided by @Jeeped):

[image: Greater or equal than example]

For strict inequality comparisons use `SQRT(_)^2` as pointed out by @Tom Sharpe.

Comment: I haven't tested your maths but it looks correct; I'll test the next time this situation shows up.

Comment: I use double-reciprocation with unity myself, plus various others (e.g., for excluding negative numbers, taking the square root then squaring), depending on the situation: https://excelxor.com/2014/09/25/iferror-techniques-for-excluding-certain-values-from-results/

Comment: I thought about using SQRT and ^2. Seems to give slightly different result when REALLY-LONG-FORMULA=threshold?

Comment: It's a very resourceful and charming solution, but now it happens that my `threshold` is in itself a REALLY_LONG_FORMULA. Bummer...

Comment: @vicmortelmans With modern Excel you should rather use LET which makes the answer above obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, and I thought the above LN solution was very creative.

However, in case others find their way here like I did, in 2020 Microsoft 365 added the LET function which allows you to define variables within a formula. The result is a bit more intuitive for anyone who might be following up on your work or if you are coming back to something you might have created a long time ago.

So for above, you can replace:
=IF(REALLY_LONG_FORMULA>=threshold,0,REALLY_LONG_FORMULA)

with this:
=LET(varRLF,REALLY_LONG_FORMULA,IF(varRLF>=threshold,0,varRLF))

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I completely agree. Modern Excel 365 is almost a new language, using LET and Dynamic (#SPILL) arrays has made Excel really powerful and there's almost nothing that requires VBA or cumbersome workarounds anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comparing against a `threshold` amount, I would consider checking out ExcelJet's recent blog post about
[Replacing Ugly IFs with MAX() or MIN()](https://exceljet.net/replace-ugly-ifs-with-max-or-min).

Also, the `MAX()` and `MIN()` functions are much more intuitive than using lessor known functions like `EXP()` and `LN()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do use MAX and MIN where possible. However (and correct me if I'm wrong), I don't think MAX and MIN work when there is a discontinuity in the function. For example MAX(threshold, X) will be equal to threshold for X<threshold and equal to X thereafter. However if I want the function to equal 0 when X<threshold and then equal to X thereafter, I don't think this can be achieved with MAX. Let me know if you can find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing Ln Exp with SQRT ^2:-

[image]

because SQRT(0) gives 0 but ln(0) gives #NUM!

So you can choose which one to use depending whether you want the equality or not.

These also work for negative numbers - in theory.

[image]

Comment: That's a great observation. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Also tested it with a negative threshold (see edit) which should work in theory, but in practice you run into rouble with rounding errors. That's why I'm a bit dubious about these functions because you can't guarantee that you will always get back to the number you first thought of.