# How to improve the formula writing and avoid repeating the entire formula depending on the condition

Tags: excel, formula

So, say I have at cell A1:

> =IF(A2=1,A2,0)

That OK, that's a tiny formula easy to understand.
If the formula starts to grow, I would have something like:

> IF(...big formula here...=1,...repeat the big formula here...,0)

It's a dummy example but the key point here is that when I repeat the big formula at the TRUE condition position the formula double its size, what can  hinder the formula debugging, for example.

Is there a way to not repeat the whole formula writting at this situation?
I don't want to use any macro/VBA to do this or any other 'helper' cells.

Thanks

Comment: With the correct absolute/relative cell addressing, most formulas can be dragged/copied/filled to other locations. Supply hte formula and your desired action(s).

Comment: AFAIK, not if you use the `IF` statement.  But, you might be able to change the logic, depending on the expected outcomes of your real formula.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you don't have to use an IF statement, can just use

```
=--(A2=1)
```

Or for some other value, say 2,

```
=(A2=2)*2
```

These work if one of the results you want is zero.

It is a little more difficult if you have an IF statement like

```
=IF(A2>2,A2,2)
```

but you can often use MAX or MIN to avoid the IF statement

```
=MAX(A2,2)
```

If you had a chain of IF statements to divide the number in A2 into ranges like

```
=IF(A2>=2,20,IF(A2>=1,10,0))
```

You could replace it with a lookup

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,{1,10;2,20},2),0)
```

Sometimes you can replace a series of IF statements with CHOOSE, e.g. to return "Negative", "Positive" or "Zero"

```
=CHOOSE(SIGN(A2)+2,"Negative","Zero","Positive")
```

One tricky way I have seen is to use inverse functions one of which gives an error under certain conditions, so you could try

```
=IFERROR((SQRT(A2-2)^2)+2,2)
```

but I'm not sure I could recommend it as these methods can be vulnerable to rounding errors.

[See this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665435/how-do-i-avoid-repeating-long-formulas-in-excel-when-working-with-comparisons/39666769#39666769)

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper column -- say, col X -- that calculates your `big formula`. Hide the column if you don't want to confuse other spreadsheet viewers.

Then your long, difficult to debug formula becomes `IF(X1=1,...X1...,0)`.